# Is there any tool to see the queries run against the database?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, linq-to-sql, reporting

Is there any tool that will inspect either asp.net or sql server and report all the queries that are run against the database?  The reason I ask is I am using Linq for a project and want to double check what its actually doing for each page.

Ideally I'd like to view a page in a browser and have a report of all the queries that were run to create that page.

I know I can view the SQL it runs for individual queries using debugging/breakpoints, and I know about LinqPad, but I'm afraid Linq is making several more queries on its own to get related data that I may not be directly aware of.  Is there anything (tool/program/report/etc) like what I described?  Thanks!

EDIT: Is there any *FREE* tool that can do this?  I am using Sql Server 2008 Express and don't have SQL Profiler unfortunately.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Absolutely, There is a SQL tool called [SQL Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa173918%28SQL.80%29.aspx).  It does require elevated database permissions in order to run profiler.

There is a decent tutorial on how to run Profiler on [TechRepublic](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-5054787.html).

Another option out there is the [NHibernate Profiler](http://nhprof.com/).  I know that it is not as "free" as SQL Profiler, have never used it, but the screen shots for it look pretty cool.

Answer (score 3):

Profiler is the best tool of them all for this but it can be expensive in inexperienced hands.

You can also try to do "exec sp_who" and then a "dbcc inputbuffer (111)" - just put the process id in the place of 111.

Answer (score 2):

[SQL Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa173918(SQL.80).aspx) does that.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using SQL Server Express, how about this tool?

[Profiler for Microsoft SQL Server 2005/2008 Express Edition](http://sqlprofiler.googlepages.com/)

> Microsoft SQL Server family includes
>   free Express edition, that is fully
>   functional, however has some
>   disappointing limitations which
>   prevent from using it in development
>   process. One of them is absense of
>   profiling tools, standard SQL profiler
>   is not included. However, now you have
>   an ability to use express edition for
>   tuning your system. SQL Server Express
>   Edition Profiler provides the most of
>   functionality standard profiler does,
>   such as choosing events to profile,
>   setting filters, etc. By now there are
>   no analogue free tools.

[Download Here](http://code.google.com/p/sqlexpressprofiler/downloads/list)

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty way to log LINQ to SQL queries in ASP.NET is this (assuming a Northwind.Dbml):

```
NorthwindDataContext context = new NorthwindDataContext();
context.Log = Response.Output;
```

This will write all queries to the response stream. Nasty, but handy for instant gratification without need for debuggers or profilers etc.

Answer (score 0):

For the LINQ to SQL queries specifically, you can also use the [`DataContext.Log`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.log.aspx) property to output the queries to a `TextWriter`, so you can do things like write to debugger output window or (as in my use) to log4net.

These links might help:

- [Log to debugger output window, file, or memory](http://damieng.com/blog/2008/07/30/linq-to-sql-log-to-debug-window-file-memory-or-multiple-writers)
- [Log to log4net](http://devintelligence.com/2008/01/sending-the-linq-to-sql-log-to-log4net/)

Won't cover the stuff not generated by L2S, so this may not be the end all solution for you... but I've found it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This one is only free for the first 45 days, but it gives you runtime profiling/logging with a bunch of filter options, SQL Server query execution plan logging etc. Built specifically for profiling L2S apps:

http://www.huagati.com/L2SProfiler